# Are uninitialized struct members guaranteed to have a value?

Tags: c#, struct, default-value, initializer-list

If you use an initializer list to create a `struct`, do the members you leave out get a known default value?

```
public struct Testing
{
    public int i;
    public double d;
    public string s;
}

Testing test = new Testing { s="hello" };
```

I found a link at Microsoft that implies it but does not state so explicitly: [Default Values Table (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

A small test program shows that it does not generate a compiler error and produces the expected results. I know better than to rely on simple tests for guarantees though. http://ideone.com/nqFBIZ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they contain default(T) where T is the type of the value.
Object references will be null.

Excerpt:

> As described in Section 5.2, several kinds of variables are
>   automatically initialized to their default value when they are
>   created. For variables of class types and other reference types, this
>   default value is null. However, since structs are value types that
>   cannot be null, the default value of a struct is the value produced by
>   setting all value type fields to their default value and all reference
>   type fields to null.

Taken from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475(v=vs.71).aspx

I remember when studying the MOC for the certification that they explicitly state this. It is a guaranteed feature of the language.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on pid's answer:

```
test = new Testing { s = hello }
```

is specified as having the semantics of:

```
Testing temp = new Testing();
temp.s = "hello";
test = temp;
```

The *default constructor* of a value type is documented as the constructor which sets all the fields of the instance to their default values.

More generally, the C# language requires that *any* constructor of a value type have the property that all fields be *definitely assigned* before the constructor terminates normally.

Now, if no constructor is called then there are two cases. If the variable is *initially assigned* then the variable acts the same as though the default constructor was called. For example, if you say

```
Testing[] test = new Testing[1];
```

Then `test[0]` is initialized to the default value the same as if you'd said

```
Testing[] test = new Testing[1] { new Testing() };
```

If the variable is *not initially assigned*, for example, a local variable, then *you* are required to definitely assign all the fields before you read them.  That is, if we have a local:

```
Testing test;
test.s = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(test.d); // ERROR, test.d has not been written yet.
```

Note also that mutable structs are a worst practice in C#. Instead, make a public constructor that sets all the fields, make the fields private, and put property getters on top of them.